# How to implement custom method in custom spring repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I would like to have a method, which is obtaining super main customer, which has `id=0`.

I have Customer class:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

[According to dox](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), I should create two additional classes/interfaces.

So I have `CustomerCustom` interface:

```
public interface CustomerCustom {

   Customer getVeryMainCustomer();

}
```

where a method `getVeryMainCustomer` declared.

Then my exposure repository interface turns following:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>, CustomerCustom {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

it extends both `CrudRepository` and my `CustomerCustom`.

But next I should implement `CustomerCustom`. But how to do that?

I wrote

```
public class CustomerCustomImpl implements CustomerCustom {

   @Override
   public Customer getVeryMainCustomer() {
      return null;
   }


}
```

bot don't know, what to write in implementation. How to reach customer?

Comment: What is the method supposed to do? Did you think about using `@Query`? What is the table structure or `Customer`?

Comment: Table structure of Customer is defined by JPA automatically on the basis of `Customer` class definition. The method is supposed to select the customer with ID = 0. Yes, I would like to use `@Query` if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

With [`@Query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query):

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = 0")
    Customer getVeryMainCustomer();
}
```

Spring-data will handle the implementation for you using the query from the annotation.

Comment: But this is inside extending interface. Is it possible to use `@Query` in my custom repository implementation?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, why would you still need a custom repository impl with this solution?

Comment: Ok, you are right, per stated question this is sufficient. But suppose I just want both to implement repository and add some queries?

Comment: Then use @Query in the interface for spring and do your stuff in your impl as you did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject entitymanager in the class for your queries

```
public class CustomerCustomImpl implements CustomerCustom {

    //This is my tip, but not a must...
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void save(...){
        //do what you need here

       Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1);// example of employye
    }
}
```

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve